# KafkaProducer: IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Kafka producer throws the following exception when record is sent to kafka topic:

```
{\"log\":\"java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2020-10-23T12:48:50.415014714Z\"}"}
 java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2020-10-23T12:48:50.41502027Z\"}"}
org.apache.kafka.common.utils.SystemTime.waitObject(SystemTime.java:55)\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2020-10-23T12:48:50.415024923Z\"}"}
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerMetadata.awaitUpdate(ProducerMetadata.java:119)\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2020-10-23T12:48:50.415029863Z\"}"}
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:1029)\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2020-10-23T12:48:50.415034336Z\"}"}
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:883)\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2020-10-23T12:48:50.415038722Z\"}"}
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:862)\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2020-10-23T12:48:50.415042939Z\"}"}
org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:781)\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2020-10-23T12:48:50.415047238Z\"}"}
org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:562)\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2020-10-23T12:48:50.415051555Z\"}"}
org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:369)\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2020-10-23T12:48:50.415055882Z\"}"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: anything new regarding this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug on the Kafka producer component at the moment, the relevant JIRA ticket is below.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10902